# Implemetation of SOA with CQRS

Tags: architecture, soa, cqrs

I am trying to implement a asp.net mvc4 website. This website is supposed to built on the principles of service oriented architecture (i.e all the different modules like patients ,users will be separated as a service). This website is a plain website which calls web services which in turn talk with the CQRS  layer of the service/module. I wanted to know whether this is a right architecture for a web project.  My database is a multi-tenanted database. Do you think it would be better if i removed the web service layer?. Right now i have implemented the project using wcf web services and everything works fine but just wanted to have an idea if i could anything else to make the architecture  better

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably recommend taking steps to a more asynchronous command model rather than one built around blocking request/response web services (same goes for WCF and Web API).

You might also be well served by a publish/subscribe event-based synchronization model to some read-model (which could be a cache) improving the performance and the simplicity of your queries.

In terms of infrastructure, a service bus like [NServiceBus](http://particular.net/nservicebus) or [Mass Transit](http://masstransit-project.com/) could be a good choice. There is also a project called [NCQRS](http://ncqrs.codeplex.com/) but it appears to be in alpha (and I haven't used it myself) so I'm not sure if I could recommend it for production use.

Comment: By asynchronous command model i am guessing you mean the async library of asp.net MVC4, even then i would be calling a web service or web api be it asynchronously. In terms of CQRS the idea which i had was if lets say an update or create takes place i just send the command via the WCF/Web API and update my view model and basically forget about the command atleast from UI side .

Comment: As i have developed a mock application i am observing that i don't need the even store, for now i just want any event which is coming to my service(cqrs level) to be published(using NService bus). I do want to keep the architecture for it so that later on if the need comes i can add it, do you think it right to go ahead with CQRS type infrastructure even though i am not using event storage, or would you suggest some other architecture.

Comment: If you are doing an async command invocation, why not use the bus to send the message directly? There are only drawbacks in using RPC infrastructure there. With regards to the event storage, I agree that that is something you can wait with.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a web service from Web application is fine. Better use AJAX in this case to make it more efficient. Now a days we have ASP.NET Web API(http://www.asp.net/web-api) to create Restful service (instead of WCF web service). Using ASP.NET Web API is simple and need less configuration stuff. Those are two points you may consider as of now if possible. Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking of using angular js and calling json web services but that would again be a web service only.